# Are there Coherent Cosheaves?

Tags: sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

Is there a well-defined notion of coherent cosheaves in a similar sense to coherent sheaves? If so, what properties do they hold?

Comment: There are these things called "contraherent cosheaves" which may be relevant: http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2995

Comment: Shouldn't that be "herent cosheaves"? ;)